# CSS - Bootstrap navbar-header vertical middle

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I get the brand to be vertical middle on custom size navbar?

```
.navbar {
    min-height: 120px;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a {
    line-height: 120px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0tkaya44/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this : http://jsfiddle.net/0tkaya44/1/

add this in your css:

```
.navbar-brand {
float: left;
height: 150px;
padding: 0 20px;
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 150px;
}
```